# A simple upper bound.

Tags: inequality

Does $$\frac{1}{\Big|e^{\frac{2\pi a\sqrt{-1}}q} - 1\Big|} < q^{1/2}*(\log q)^2$$ always hold at any $0<a<q$ at every larg enough $q\in\Bbb N$?

Is there a proof?

Can this be tightened to $$\frac{1}{\Big|e^{\frac{2\pi a\sqrt{-1}}q} - 1\Big|} < cq^{1/2}*\log q$$ at some fixed $c>0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.** Take $a=1$, and let $q\to\infty$.

$$\lvert e^{\frac{2i\pi}{q}} - 1\rvert = \left\lvert \frac{2i\pi}{q} + o(\left(\frac{1}{q}\right) \right\rvert \operatorname*{\sim}_{q\to\infty} \frac{2\pi}{q}$$
so the LHS is asymptotically equivalent to $\frac{q}{2\pi}$. Since the RHS  is
$
\sqrt{q}\log^2 q = o(q)
$, the inequality cannot hold when $q$ grows large.

Comment: would you know similar problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2108106/a-simple-upper-bound-2?

Comment: @ao. Why did you delete that other question?( I was in the process of typing an answer.)

Comment: I thought there was a mistake. Sorry brought back up.