# A simple upper bound - $2$.

Tags: inequality

Let $q$ be a large prime and fix $r\in(0,\frac12)$.

Is there a $\theta\in(\frac12,1)$ such that $\Bigg|\frac{e^{2\pi iaq^r}-1}{e^{2\pi i\frac aq}-1}\Bigg|<q^\theta$ holds at any fixed $a\neq0\bmod q$?

Comment: Do you mean "any" or "every" here?

Comment: @ClementC. at least "almost every" and preferably "every".

Answer (score 0):

**No,** at least not for *every* $a$. *(The counterexample below uses $a=1$, but should, I think, generalize to $a=o(q)$.)*

Namely, for the following: $r=\frac{1}{4}$, and $q=n^4+2n^3 + o(n^3)$ for a large integer $n$ (think of $n\to\infty$). Then, for $a=1$
$$
aq^r = \left(n^4+2n^3 + o(n^3)\right)^{1/4} = n+\frac{1}{2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
$$
so that the numerator is $$
\left\lvert e^{2\pi i a q^r} -1\right\rvert
=\left\lvert e^{2\pi i n+i\pi+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)} -1\right\rvert
=\left\lvert e^{i\pi+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)} -1\right\rvert
=\left\lvert -2 + o(1)\right\rvert = 2+o(1) \tag{1}
$$
while the numerator is
$$
\left\lvert e^{2i\pi\frac{a}{q}}-1\right\rvert
= \left\lvert 2i\pi\frac{1}{q} + o\left(\frac{1}{q}\right)\right\rvert
= \frac{2\pi}{q} + o\left(\frac{1}{q}\right). \tag{2}
$$

Combining the two, your LHS is asymptotically equivalent to 
$$
\left\lvert \frac{e^{2\pi i a q^r} -1}{e^{2i\pi\frac{a}{q}}-1}\right\rvert\operatorname*{\sim}_{q\to\infty}\frac{q}{\pi}
$$
so for any $\theta < 1$ and large enough $q$ it cannot be upper bounded by $q^\theta$.

Comment: $q$ is a prime.

Comment: It is now? Dammit, it used not to be. That is fine though, you can still find a prime there.

Comment: I think it does not matter. Full question is here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/260201/elementary-simple-finite-field-estimates.

Comment: I made an edit -- hopefully this solves the prime issue.

Comment: yeah i think it does. Can you look at the other link also? Even if that works it will be good. Do you want me to post on math.stackexchange instead of mathoverflow?

Comment: I cannot at the moment -- I have to take off.